# What is the best map to farm gold?

Tags: fire-emblem-warriors

I want to make sure all of my units are close in level and seals, in case I am forced to use certain ones I normally wouldn't bring along. Obviously the best way for that is to make use of the Training Camp, but it can get pretty pricy.

What is the best History map/mode or chapter for farming gold?

Answer (score 2):

The best ways to grind gold involve a lot more than just picking a map.  Most of the gold you acquire will be through **selling weapons**.  You can increase the drop rate of them by getting the **130+ kills bonus while in Awakening mode** or by using one of the **"Weapon Blessings"** (25 mementos required).  And remember that harder maps will drop better weapons that will sell for more gold.

Adding the **"Wealthy Blessing"** for 20 silver materials (25 mementos required) will increase the gold dropped by enemies.  If you have Anna, you can unlock her specific crest, **Payday**, which increases gold dropped by 1% for every luck point your hero has.

In terms of the best maps, you can go one of three ways.

1. If you want the most up-time for finding weapons, picking a long battle like the ones in **Story Mode** works best.  This has the added bonus of giving a 60k+ end-map bonus if playing on Lunatic.  This will best utilize your Blessings if you don't want to use a lot of materials.
2. You could also try to maximize your Awakening Gauge bonus by playing **"Timed Onslaught"** maps.  These are also useful for grinding silver materials (which we all need lots of).  If you kill the Transport Captiains, they'll drop a full Awakening potion which you can pick up right when your meter is about to run out.
3. Finally, if you have the DLC, you can play **"Gold Rush"** maps which have Transport Captains which specifically drop a lot of gold.  This should be combo'd with the Wealthy Blessing and Anna's Payday ability if you can.

It's difficult to determine which is best because there's so much variation in luck/damage/weapon value/etc.  Just pick which one suits your play style the most.

Comment: IIRC, weapons with more slots (or attributes, can't remember) sell for a higher price. If they use the weapon farming approach, they could potentially increase profit by using a weapon with the First Class (better chance for higher quality weapon drops) and Power Up (weapon drops have a higher chance to have more attribute slots) attributes

Answer (score 0):

If You're looking directly in Gold/Time ratio, I think playing the prologue in hardest difficulty is the best. It actually doesn't take much time if you skip all minions, and skip cinematics, and earn ~13K gold. But it isn't fun at all.

Maybe another map, if you sell the weapons you've dropped?